# TestCafe. How can I see the list of all opened browser tabs?

Tags: testcafe

I'm trying to use TestCafe with multiple browser tabs.
I have an web page which loads js scripts. An automated click into an overlay opens a new browser tab.
The tab is opened in the browser.
"*await t.eval(() => document.documentURI)*" always returns the initial web page url.
"*disableNativeAutomation*" property in the base configuration file always opens new windows. Not new browser tabs.

How can I see the list of all opened browser tabs?
How can I change the tabs?

I've read a lots of stuff and nothing helped me.
I'll be very thankful if someone helps me or tell me that such feature is not implemented yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe supports only multiple windows by design, not multiple tabs. New tabs are opened in Native Automation mode instead of new windows due to [limitations of native automation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/intermediate-guides/native-automation-mode#q-what-are-the-limitations-of-native-automation).

Refer to the following issue for updates: [Support multiple windows in native automation mode](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7661).

Comment: Does TestCafe team plan to implement multiple tabs support?

Comment: The browser stops JavaScript execution in background tabs. This breaks the normal operation of the tested website.
This is why, TestCafe opens new tabs in browser windows.
If you need to manipulate the browser tabs, consider using another testing tool.